# How can I extract a .bz2 files directly into an external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, zip

I have a large .bz2 file of 18 gigabytes and there's no way it will extract on to my very small computer storage. So I got an external hard drive, copied the file to it, and pressed 'extract' expecting it to extract to the hard drive. About 1/4 the way through, it stopped because it ran out of space because it was expanding on my computer storage, not the drive's.

I then looked at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197165/extract-zip-directly-to-external-hard-drive) question and tried to extract it like so but it turns out .bz2 is not .zip (obviously) so when I tried putting this command in terminal:

```
unzip /Volumes/My\ Passport\ for\ Mac/lichess_db_standard_rated_2020-10.pgn.bz2 -d/Volumes/My\ Passport\ for\ Mac
```

it gave me the following error:

```
Archive:  /Volumes/My Passport for Mac/lichess_db_standard_rated_2020-10.pgn.bz2
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /Volumes/My Passport for Mac/lichess_db_standard_rated_2020-10.pgn.bz2 or
        /Volumes/My Passport for Mac/lichess_db_standard_rated_2020-10.pgn.bz2.zip, and cannot find /Volumes/My Passport for Mac/lichess_db_standard_rated_2020-10.pgn.bz2.ZIP, period.
```

How can I extract this .bz2 into a hard drive directly?

Comment: How did you initially attempt to unpack the file on the external drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unarchiver is a great tool where mac os's own extractor comes in short. You can download the utility via [official website](http://theunarchiver.com).

Once installed just open the app via Spotlight search or something. The preferences windows will open.

[image: Pref]

Make sure to activate bzip2 file archive type.

[image: Extraction]

When you head to Extraction section of the preferences, you can click the dropdown menu mentioned as "Extract archives to:" and select "Ask for a destination folder".

Then, when you try to extract anything, you can select the destination folder as desired.

I hope this utility solves the issue for you. Feel free to comment if anything goes wrong.

Cheers!

Update: In order to extract to an external drive, you have to create a new folder inside the storage unit for unarchiver getting write permissions to your hard-disk. Minor thing mentioned by question owner in comments down below.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you very very much for the help. But there is an important piece of information I found out while implementing your solution: You cannot extract straight to your drive. If you try this, it will say the file is not writeable. But don't worry, all you have to do is make a new folder in the drive and then make it extract to that folder instead. Also I totally upvoted you it just didn't show because my rep is below 15

Comment: @maxijazz I am a bit OCD when it comes to file management. Everything needs to be organized in my virtual environment (perks of being a sound technician and dealing with endless wires.). Didn't noticed that, updating the thread it maybe helpful to someone else as well.